# Convert DateTime to UTC without changing date or time on TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is an example

```
var testDate = new Date("2021-05-17T00:00:00"); // this is local date time
```

I want to convert this Date into UTC without changing value for date and time
i.e 2021-05-17T00:00:00 should be identified as  UTC date time and in browser, it should be displayed as local time which is 2021-05-17T05:45:00 (my current timezone)

Comment: `var testDate = new Date("2021-05-17T00:00:00Z");`

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Can you also add it as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indicate that an ISO date is in the UTC timezone by placing `Z` at the end.

Seems to work:

```js
var testDate = new Date("2021-05-17T00:00:00Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate an **ISO** date in the **UTC** timezone by placing **Z** at the end.

This Should Work:

```
var testDate = new Date("2021-05-17T00:00:00Z");
```